# Why 'H2219 Private symbol X declared but never used' occurs when using an overloaded procedure only after assigning it to a local variable?

Tags: delphi, overloading, compiler-warnings, delphi-2007

I'm using a private method only after assigning it to a local variable:

```
  TMyTestWithoutParam = procedure() of object;
  TMyTestIntegerParam = procedure(APar : integer) of object;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure  Test(); overload;
    procedure  Test(APar : integer); overload;
  end;
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TmpA : TMyTestWithoutParam;
  TmpB : TMyTestIntegerParam;
begin
  TmpA := Test;
  TmpA();

  TmpB := Test;
  TmpB(1);
end;

procedure  TForm1.Test();
begin
  //...
end;

procedure  TForm1.Test(APar : Integer);
begin
  //...
end;
```

On compile, it raises **H2219** warning message:

> [DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(16): H2219 Private symbol 'Test' declared but
>   never used

Why does **H2219** warning occurs and which is the right way for avoid that?

Comment: It's a compiler defect that has long been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested it using *Delphi XE7* and can't reproduce the problem. I think it has been fixed in newer IDE's versions.

Under *Delphi 2007*, the warning can be avoided by turning off/on the hints

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    {$HINTS OFF}
    procedure  Test(); overload;
    procedure  Test(APar : integer); overload;
    {$HINTS ON}
  end;
```